# Does AWS ECS fargate shutdown container if CPU reaches 100%?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpu, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have setup a ecs task with one container using fargate. The task and container have cpu and memory limits set. I can see that my container will shutdown occasionally for some unknown reason. At the time of shutdown and restart the max cpu is 100% and the minimum 0%.

I am trying to workout if the container shuts down due to my application hitting some limit internally or AWS shutting it down when the CPU hits 100%. I know memory is a hard limit which triggers a shutdown but I don't know if CPU is the same way?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked what was the exit code for that container? Sometime we have the same problem and I can see that docker kills the container with exit code 137 and the status reason: OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due too memory usage. I have never seen any error related to CPU usage even our containers use CPU very intensively. More info on how to check exit status here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/stopped-task-errors.html

Comment: Thanks you, it appeared to be a cpu issue since looking at metrics the memory did not hit 100% but the max CPU did. However I thought this could be due to the container restarting since the max was 100% and the minimum 0%. So it died sending it to 0% then restarted sending it to 100%. Of course that was contentious in the office since we fixed the restart issue by increasing the memory and cpu. So by there reasoning it must be cpu since it could not be memory, since it never hit 100%, and it could not be something to do with the app since more cpu and memory fixed it. Will check the code.

Answer (score 3):

Your observation is absolutely true, If you are using Fargate Launch type, its mandatory to give [Task Size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#task_size) because for Fargate pricing calculation is based on Task Size and in case if application tries to consume more resource(CPU or Memory) than specified its size, they are killed and you'll exit code as 137, which seems logical.

This situation can be addressed in two ways:

1. Benchmark application against load and set appropriate Task Size.
2. If load is unpredictable, use service autoscaling based on service CPU Utilization and Application Load Balancer in front of Fargate service, this will scale out your service under load conditions and will scale in when there is no CPU utilization.

I hope this will help in stabilizing your micro application.

Comment: Also be aware that a memory limit is *mandatory* but it won't tell you. I accidentally left it out and it killed my process after only 128MB RAM used, but left the container running forever!